# Getting artwork from current track in Applescript

Tags: applescript, itunes, artwork

I'm trying to make a script to pull the artwork of the currently playing track and write it to a file. I've checked out a few guides but none of them seem to work, any tips?

```
tell application "iTunes"
write artwork 1 to "path:to:desktop" of type("JPEG")
end tell
```

To be honest I've no idea what I'm doing. Anyone feeling helpful?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write `raw data of artwork 1 of current track` to a file:

```
-- get the raw bytes of the artwork into a var
tell application "iTunes" to tell artwork 1 of current track
    set srcBytes to raw data
    -- figure out the proper file extension
    if format is «class PNG » then
        set ext to ".png"
    else
        set ext to ".jpg"
    end if
end tell

-- get the filename to ~/Desktop/cover.ext
set fileName to (((path to desktop) as text) & "cover" & ext)
-- write to file
set outFile to open for access file fileName with write permission
-- truncate the file
set eof outFile to 0
-- write the image bytes to the file
write srcBytes to outFile
close access outFile
```

You might also use http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=savealbumart, but it doesn't include source code.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I didn't realise you could send a 'tell' to the object artwork within the app.