# Change an iMessage icon?

Tags: shell, applescript, imessage

I've googled & searched the site for this with no luck, and you guys were such great help last time. I was hoping someone might have an idea of how to change the current users iMessage icon through Applescript? I have looked through the Messages suite under the applescript library and found that there under the class 'application' there is a property 'image'. The description of which is "My image as it appears in all services". It does not appear to be read only.

I am trying to change that property, but in my limited knowledge of Applescript it does not appear to be working. Here's what I've got:

```
tell application "Messages"
    set image to NewImage
end tell
```

NewImage in this case is a POSIX file path (which I'm not sure is right either) ;\

(OSX Yosemite by the way)
Thanks :]

Comment: You are not describing your issue very well.  For what purpose do you want to change the icon?  Are you changing it once? On a trigger? On a schedule?

Comment: I updated the info to give people a better idea :D

Comment: Run "get image" to see the format (data). I assume it must be set in the same format but to create the data from an image is something else.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I added get image and looked in the replies when I ran. I see a big long hex number followed by the word "data" in blue. I assume this means that it wants "data" instead of a "POSIX file" path as I have provided. 

How wpuld I set the file at that path to be the "data"?

Comment: Here are discussions about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597696/how-to-manipulate-data-objects-in-applescript/27611835 and check out the links (also the one in the answer's comment)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Good find on this discussion. From what I can tell those code snippets only read or write to data files using a string. I'd still need to decipher the actual hex string though, right? 

To write into that data file, I'd need to write the information in hex format? Yikes.